# python sending email with text and attachment

Tags: python, smtp

I wrote a script for backing up my Neo4J DB.

At the end of the backup process and email is sent to the DB Administrator

The email received without the `message_body`.

This is the code:

```
message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['To'] = "Database Admin <%s>" % _receiver
message['From'] = "Pico.buzz Graph Database <%s>" % _sender
if not log.is_error():
    message['Subject'] = "Graph DB Backup Finished Successfully"
    message_body = 'Successfully backup email. Please see review log file'
else:
    message['Subject'] = "ATTENTION: ERROR! Graph DB Backup Failed"
    message_body = 'An error occur during backup. please review log'
instance_name = aws.get_instance_name()
instance_details = "Instance Id: %s\nPrivate IP Address: %s" % (aws.get_instance_id(), aws.get_instance_ip())
if instance_name is not None:
    instance_details = """Instance Name: %s\n%s""" % (instance_name, instance_details)
message_body = "%s\n\n%s" % (message_body, instance_details)
content = MIMEText(message_body, 'plain')
message.attach(content)
message.attach(_get_log_file())
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
smtp.sendmail(_sender, _receiver, message.as_string())
log.info(__name__, "Successfully sent email to: %s" % _receiver)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You've confirmed that `message_body` is what you expect before your `sendmail` call I presume?

Comment: I printed it and was happy.. :)

Comment: Unrelated, but `%s` formatting is typically avoided. You should look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format).

Comment: Try changing the first line to `message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')`.

Comment: Which version of python do you use? What `type(_get_log_file())` returns? What happens, if you first attach `_get_log_file()` to the message, and the `content` (order of attachment matters)?

Comment: @erip `message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')` actually worked.. post it as an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MIMEMultipart` takes as a parameter to the constructor a multipart subtype.

You were using the subtype `'alternative'`. The alternative subtype allows the email to be sent with HTML and text.

You wanted to submit an email with text and an attachment, so you need to construct `MIMEMultipart` with the subtype `'mixed'`.

For more details about these subtypes, you can look at the MIME Wikipedia entry on [Multipart messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).